# VBA Menu and Toolbars Went Missing

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2003

The toolbars (menu bar and quick access bar) are missing in the Visual Basic Editor in Excel. What happened? I can't click anywhere to find them to enable again!

e.g. -

[image]
[full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IymyB.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sometimes happens if you leave the VBE open and the computer goes to sleep or hibernates. It's difficult to reproduce, but there's a simple fix -

**Just close the VBE window and reopen it.** *I know, this is your default first troubleshooting step, but you forgot it in haste. It's OK, I won't tell anyone.*

[MS KB829059](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829059/en-us) talks about Outlook 2003 and 2007, but this applies across the entire Office Suite in 2003 and 2007.

Comment: I believe the first thing to check would be View ► Toolbars ► Standard. Stating *"I can't click anywhere to find them"* without specifying what has actually been tried is completely useless.

Comment: @Jeeped, that might be possible if the menu bar was shown...

Comment: @jbarker2160 - good point. I should have specified trying Alt+V, T to see if the menus commands are available but not visible.

Comment: @Jeeped you should add that to the answer as a first-step.

Comment: @Raystafarian your advice is still helping people today.  Thanks for that answer

Comment: @Raystafarian I've got the same problem with Office 2016 and re-opening the VBE window doesn't help! I also tried the following code in the direct window, without success: `Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Visible = True
Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Position = msoBarTop
Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).RowIndex = 0` Any other hints?

Comment: @Joe what's missing?

Comment: @Raystafarian Same as in the question - menu bar and quick access bar. But I think I found the solution now. I had the Tablet Mode activated in Windows 10. After I deactivated it and reopened the VBE, the menu bar and quick access bar appeared again.

Comment: @Raystafarian And thanks from 2020, where it's *still* a bug in Office '16.